# Ajax triggers error even when success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is the first time I worked with Ajax in combination with PHP and I'm having a hard time getting it to work.

I have this piece of Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
            url:  '/dev/php/login.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function(date) {
                console.log(date);
                alert("Het emailadres of wachtwoord is onjuist");
            },
            data: {email:email,password:password},
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                alert(response);
            }
        })
```

With this PHP code:

```
<?php
$servername = "blur";
$username = "blur";
$dbpassword = "blur";
$dbname = "blur";

$emailadres = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $dbpassword, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$encodedpass = md5($password);

$sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM account WHERE `email`='$emailadres' AND `password`='$encodedpass'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Name: " . $row["first_name"]. " " . $row["last_name"] . " WEEEE";
    }
}

else {
if (!function_exists('http_response_code'))
{
    function http_response_code($newcode = NULL)
    {
        static $code = 200;
        if($newcode !== NULL)
        {
            header('X-PHP-Response-Code: '.$newcode, true, $newcode);
            if(!headers_sent())
                $code = $newcode;
        }       
        return $code;
    }
}
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

For some reason the error function in Ajax always gets called, even when the response text echoes me the name from the database. It looks like this:

[image: The console.log data when the username and password is correct]

Comment: Move data before error?

Comment: You're telling jQuery that the response will be JSON (`dataType: 'json'`) which it clearly isn't (which the second and third parameter of the `error` would have told you)

Comment: @Andreas thank you for your passive agressive, but helpful comment

Comment: No aggression intended :)

Comment: Are you sure the json you should send back is valid, if you need to send back json its not that hard in php try to use json_encode(<<your array here>>);

Comment: @Andreas no hard feelings :)